# How can I rewrite subquery inside JOIN?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, subquery

I'm not very fluent in SQL and my question is how can I rewrite the following statement to make it look more natural. The `select` I'm trying to write joins two tables -- "users" and "stats" -- and I know id's of users in advance. It's probably something very basic but I'm not an SQL ninja yet.

```
select
    u.id,
    sum(s.xxx)
from
    (
        select id from users where id in (100, 200, 300)
    ) u
    left join
    stats s
        on u.id = s.user_id
group by
    u.id
;
```

The part that looks strange is

```
    (
        select id from users where id in (100, 200, 300)
    ) u
```

Suggest me the right way. Thanks

Comment: You aren't using any fields from stats (s) in this query, why would you include it?

Comment: You're right. I mistyped: it's `sum(s.xxx)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a complicated way of saying

....`WHERE id in (100,200,300)`

In  your `WHERE` clause.

The whole thing could be rewritten as:

```
select
    u.id,
    sum(s.xxx)
from
    users u
left join stats s
    on s.user_id = u.id
where u.id in (100, 200, 300)
group by
    u.id
```

Comment: I'm sorry. A typo. Gonna fix... It's `sum(s.xxx)`

Comment: @user466619 - I altered my query for this.

Comment: @JNK -- it runs much slower on existing database with thousands of users when there are several known id's I use in IN expression

Comment: @user466619 - This should run just as fast as your previous query, if not faster.  Instead of doing a subselect with an `IN` clause, you are doing an explicit `IN` clause on its own.  `IN` is not a super fast operation in general, but it probably is the best solution here.

Comment: @JNK -- Sorry for that, __now__ it appears to be as fast as :) Still, is there a way to filter users before the whole table is passed to JOIN? Sorry if this question doesn't make sense

Comment: @user466619 - It makes sense, but that's not really how SQL works.  If it's running slowly, check your indexes.  Do you have an index on u.id?  Do you have an index on s.user_id?  If you don't that will make this a much slower query than it needs  to be.